# How do I benchmark the test suite of a Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to optimise a test suite. First I need to know where the time is being spent. As a minimun I want to know how much time is spent in each test.

I came across this gem `https://github.com/timocratic/test_benchmark` but is no longer maintained.

Notice that my goal is to benchmark the test suite, not the application.

Is there any other gem that I could use?

- Rails
- Rspec
- Capybara

Comment: well, why don't you use tools presented here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html

Comment: @apneadiving: Notice that I want to benchmark __the test suite__, not the application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rspec has a minimum functionality profiler included. Have you looked at it? ([blog post tutorial for rspec1 but still valid for rspec2](http://www.idolhands.com/ruby-on-rails/specs-and-testing/tracking-down-slow-running-examples-in-rspec))

Basically, if you specify `-p` then you get a list of the slowest 10 tests.

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiar with the unix time command?  If you're just looking to see how long your test suite took to run you can just prepend the time commmand:

```
time rake spec
```

After your rspec output you should see something like

```
Finished in 5.31 seconds
195 examples, 0 failures, 27 pending

real    0m26.580s
user    0m14.085s
sys     0m2.168s
```

Of course, this is assuming you're on a *nix platform :-)

-a